# Cannot parse int from string (strange)

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm trying to parse int from string.
Am I crazy or just blind?

Here is an image from immediate window right before i got System.FormatException:

[image: immediate window]

I have string value "35" in variable *line* (I wrote line and it returned "35" as above)

If i try to parse this line i got an exception.
But if I'm parsing "35" by directly writing it into int.Parse method, it works OK. Maybe it's late, maybe I'm blind but I don't see any error here. Embarassing question to ask on SO but maybe someone could see something.

Best regards

**EDIT**

I'm trying to run some program from github. The method is:

```
public int ReadLineAsInt()
    {
        string line = ReadLine();
        return Int32.Parse(line);
    }
```

It reads lines from text file.
The method ReadLine is quite old and quite strange, but it gives me string with number which I'm expecting:

[image]

_file is just StreamReader

Comment: Is `line`'s length 2 or 4? In other words, does it have the double quotes inside the string?

Comment: `line` probably has some non printable characters messing the parsing up. Examine `line.Length`

Comment: try to check "line == "35" before calling int.Parse: possibly that "line" has somehow changed when you call Parse

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  I've seen issues with the immediate window in VS 2015.

Comment: A screenshot of your immediate window is not enough. Write a short but compilable program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: May be there is a non printable character, try `int.Parse(new string(line.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));` if that works then you check the length of `line` and make sure it is 2 for `"35"`

Answer (score 0):

Oh no... When i tried

```
line.ToCharArray()
```

It gave me:

```
{char[3]}
[0]: 65279 ''
[1]: 51 '3'
[2]: 53 '5'
```

And before that `line == "35"` gave me **false**.

I didn't expect that...
Running soneone's old code can be surprising at times. Thank you everyone for your time trying to help me. Special thanx to  Gian Paolo and Amit :)

Comment: thats xfeff - its a byte order mark from a Unicode file